# check for players undergoing the maximum/minimum change in time course data?

Tags: time-series, ranking

I have time series data of many variables (This data comes from high throughput biological experiments, which measure the amount of particular biological components such as RNA content of a cell etc., )

The time series looks like

$x \to x_1, x_2, x_3 $ which is the value of $x$ at time points $1,2,3$ respectively
$y \to y_1, y_2, y_3 $
etc..

Now, I would like to shortlist the set of variables which have seen the biggest jump or fall (or the ones that did not change much) in their trend. I am interested in understanding which biological players changed radically over the time course and that these may be important players driving biological mechanisms.

What is the best measure to calculate this?

Comment: Because there are many senses of "biggest," such as in terms of differences, ratios, slopes of best-fitting lines, and much more, the answer depends on what these variables are, how they are measured, and the reason you are making this selection of variables.  Please edit your post to provide this kind of information.

Comment: @whuber: thank you for your reply. I have tried to make the context from which the time course data is obtained more clear.

Comment: How many time points? Do you have biological replicates? Technical replicates?

Comment: I have 4 time points, 3 technical replicates